# How to get function from parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a couple of functional components:

```js
export default function IconModal({
    label,
    icon,
    className,
    children
}) {
    const el = useRef();
    const [ isExpanded, setExpanded ] = useState(false);
    const onClickOutside = useCallback(() => setExpanded(false), []);
    const cx = classNames('modal__wrapper', className);

    useOnClickOutside(el, onClickOutside);

    return (
        <div className={cx} aria-expanded={isExpanded} ref={el}>
            <button onClick={() => setExpanded(!isExpanded)}
                    aria-label={label}
                    className="modal__action">
                <Icon name={icon} />
            </button>

            <span className="modal">
                <button className="modal__close" onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}>
                    <Icon name="close"/>
                </button>
                {children}
            </span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And then I intend to consume it like:

```js
export default function InfoIconModal() {
    const context = useContext(SomeContext);
    const title = 'Hey Here';

    return (
        <IconModal
            className="header__modal__wrapper--info"
            label="Know more about this"
            icon="info"
        >
            <h2 className="info__subtitle text--uppercase">How This Works</h2>
            <h3 className="info__title">{title} = {context.name}</h3>
            <div className="info__body" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: context.hiw}} />
            <p className="font--semi-bold">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">View Legend</a>
            </p>
        </IconModal>
    );
}
```

Which works great. Now comes the fact that I'd like to close the modal if, in this case, the user clicks on the View Legend link but it could be any other reason.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the difference between an 'info icon modal' and an 'icon modal'? Do they have to be two separate components? If not, no functions would need to be passed and this problem would go away.

Comment: There are clear differences and I'm sure you can spot them. `IconModal` is an icon that, upon clicked, shows a modal. Whereas `InfoIconModal` is a specific implementation of the previous module. Imagine that I want to implement `ShareIconModal` which shows a modal to share and I want that upon sharing, it closes the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good use case for the `render prop` pattern, something like this :

```
export default function InfoIconModal() {
  const context = useContext(SomeContext);
  const title = 'Hey Here';

  return (
      <IconModal
          className="header__modal__wrapper--info"
          label="Know more about this"
          icon="info"
      >
      {
        ({onClose}) => (
          <h2 className="info__subtitle text--uppercase">How This Works</h2>
          <h3 className="info__title">{title} = {context.name}</h3>
          <div className="info__body" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: context.hiw}} />
          <p className="font--semi-bold">
           <a href="#" target="_blank" onClick={() => onClose()}>View Legend</a>
          </p>
        )
      }
      </IconModal>
  );
}

export default function IconModal({
  label,
  icon,
  className,
  children
}) {
  const el = useRef();
  const [ isExpanded, setExpanded ] = useState(false);
  const onClickOutside = useCallback(() => setExpanded(false), []);
  const cx = classNames('modal__wrapper', className);

  useOnClickOutside(el, onClickOutside);

  return (
      <div className={cx} aria-expanded={isExpanded} ref={el}>
          <button onClick={() => setExpanded(!isExpanded)}
                  aria-label={label}
                  className="modal__action">
              <Icon name={icon} />
          </button>

          <span className="modal">
              <button className="modal__close" onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}>
                  <Icon name="close"/>
              </button>
              {children({onClose: () => setExpanded(isExpanded => !isExpanded)})}
          </span>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Read more : https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Comment: Thanks, Mohamed, I was just writing that as an answer. Thanks for giving me the name of the pattern too!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here that you must add some props (for example `onClick`) to specific `ReactElement`, for that you have to do it explicitly or dynamically.

The straight forward way is to render the children within `IconModal` with a normal `onClick` callback.

```
export default function IconModal(...) {
  ...
  return (
    <div >
      ...
      <span>
        <p onClick={ /* close modal */ }>
          <a>
            View Legend
          </a>
        </p>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or you can map component's children and add additional properties using [`React.Children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) and [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) APIs.

```
export default function IconModal({ children, ... }) {
  ...

  const childrenWithAdditionalProps = React.Children.map(children, 
      child => React.cloneElement(child, { /* Additional Props */ }))

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <span>
        {childrenWithAdditionalProps}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For this I think you should add additional attributes for identifing which components you want to add props to, something like:

```
const additionalTriggers = {
  legend: () => console.log("hello")
};

export default function InfoIconModal() {
  return (
    <IconModal
      //                   v Tell your component which props you want to add
      additionalTriggers={additionalTriggers}
    >
      //   v Add id and check it when mapping
      <p id="legend">
        <a>View Legend</a>
      </p>
    </IconModal>
  );
}
```

Comment: Straight forward version is too tightly coupled. Mapping does not work since that would add that "onClick" to everything. The check with mapping does seem really convoluted. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: "that would add that "onClick" to everything", thats why you need some condition.

Comment: There is no other way, you must add the `onClick` property - dynamically (using the high-level apis) or explicitly (the straight forward way).

Comment: It was just the same as Mohamed just posted above. He just beat me to it!